# UICollectionViewController Push Transitions

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, push, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to implement an interface where the user drills down through successive collection views of data, and would like to have each collection view animate to the next one as it's pushed.  This has been very frustrating.

I've boiled it down to a very simple test case which I still can't get to work the way I think it ought to.

1- A UINavigationController has a UICollectionViewController which is hardwired to return a numberOfSections == 1, an itemsInSection = 8, and the backgroundColor of the cells is set to redColor in cellForItemAtIndexPath.  The associated UICollectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize is set to 80, 80.

2 - When a cell is selected I push a new UICollectionViewController which is hardwired to return a numberOfSections == 1, an itemsInSection == 30, and the backgroundColor of the cells is set to blueColor in cellForItemAtIndexPath.  The associated UICollectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize is set to 60, 60.

If I push the second controller with its useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions property set to false, the controller slides in with the proper data display (30 blue cells).  If I set useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions to true before pushing, only the layout changes on push.  The 8 red cells from the first controller are still displayed, but their size changes to 60, 60.

Apple's UICollectionViewController class reference says that when you set useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions to true, "the navigation controller performs an animated layout change between the contents of the two collection view controllers instead of the traditional push animation", but I'm only getting the layout change.

My test code is stupid simple, so not sure what I might be doing wrong here.  Does Apple's class reference misrepresent what the expected behavior should be?  Is there any reason to just change layouts when you've pushed a new controller (and theoretically a new data source)?  Is there an alternative way to animate to the next collection view?

For what it's worth, here is the only code in my test program other than returning appropriate values for numberOfSections and numberOfItems, and setting appropriate cell background colors.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let itemSize = (collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize;
    let theLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    theLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(itemSize.width - 20, itemSize.height - 20)

    let toVC = SecondCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout:theLayout)
    toVC.useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions = true
    navigationController?.pushViewController(toVC, animated:true)
}
```